# Input values not adding on keyUp jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a running code snippet that dynamically adds input boxes to a form that is working so fine, however, am trying to get totals of the values from the input boxes but nothing seem to be working. The total area is only showing 0 but not giving me correct results.

Here is my code:

JAVASCRIPT TO DISPLAY THE TABLE WITH FORM

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" value="0" data-cubics="500"/></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
```

JAVASCRIPT TO DO THE MATH

```
<script>
function total() {
    var total1 = 0;
    $('span.cubics').each(function () {
        var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
        total1 += isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
    });
    $('.totalcubics').text(total1.toFixed(2));
}

$('input.qty').keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val * $(this).data('cubics') : '');
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
    total();
});

var $form = $('#insert_form'),
    $summands = $form.find('input.qty'),
    $sumDisplay = $('span#totalquantity');

$form.keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function () {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.text(sum);
});

$('input').on({
    focus: function () {
        if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function () {
        if (this.value === '') this.value = '0';
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML CODE TO DISPLAY TOTALS

```
     <tr class="bg">
            <td width="33%">TOTAL</td>
            <td width="33%"><span id="totalquantity"></span>

            </td>
            <td width="33%"><span class="totalcubics"></span>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Any assistance to my problem is highly appreciated

Comment: try `$(document).on("keyup","input.qty",function() {})`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen its not working, its giving me more 0's on the results

Comment: This a lot of code ... *am trying to get totals of the values from the input boxes* you said .. minimize your code with code related you may think it causes this problem .. **OR** try to explain which part of code working fine and  which part not working

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef i have edited the code and i have left out what i think is causing the problem

Comment: `total()` function works??

Comment: it tries to work because it gives me 0 as my result, and even when i add more input boxes, nothing happens when i insert numbers @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: this line here `html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';` has to give me totals from this line ` html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" value="0" data-cubics="500"/></td>';` which after overall totals are displayed here `<td width="33%"><span id="totalquantity"></span>`

Comment: Is `<span class="cubics"></span>` not having any text content the problem?.

Comment: @traktor53 for some reason, `<span class="cubics"></span>` is not getting any value hence causing the whole problem of not getting the totals

Comment: See my answer regarding the problem you posted about. What goes in the span elements will affect calculation of total cubics, but I have no idea how you intend to populate the span element so can't trouble shoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
```

this mean go to the next `td` and find the `span` and there is no span in the next `td` .. you can use

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('span.cubics').text(val);
```

or

```
$(this).closest('td').next().next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
```

and while you append the row dynamically you need to use

```
$(document).on('keyup' , 'input.qty' , function () {
```

instead of

```
$('input.qty').keyup(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate `$summands` each time you add a row to the table.  Insert the line to do so after adding the row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" value="0" data-cubics="500"/></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
  $summands = $form.find('input.qty'); //***************  add this line
 });

function total() {
    var total1 = 0;
    $('span.cubics').each(function () {
        var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
        total1 += isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
    });
    $('.totalcubics').text(total1.toFixed(2));
}

$('input.qty').keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val * $(this).data('cubics') : '');
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
    total();
});

var $form = $('#insert_form'),
    $summands = $form.find('input.qty'),
    $sumDisplay = $('span#totalquantity');

$form.keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function () {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });
    $sumDisplay.text(sum);
});

$('input').on(
{
    focus: function () {
        if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function () {
        if (this.value === '') this.value = '0';
    }
});

});  // end of document ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="insert_form" onsubmit="return false">
  <table>
     <tr class="bg">
        <td width="33%">TOTAL</td>
        <td width="33%"><span id="totalquantity"></span></td>
        <td width="33%"><span class="totalcubics"></span></td>
     </tr>
  </table> 
  <button type="button" class="add">add</button>

   <table id="item_table">
   </table>
</form>
```

At the moment you are creating summands collection with no elements, before any rows have been added.

Comment: kindly help me update the line you are talking about, can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Done, complete with test HTML. The code remains incomplete, of course. _Please also read [how to create a minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference_.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be adding the totals from the input boxes, however, i have noticed that  `html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';` is not geting values, because, besides `<td width="33%"><span id="totalquantity"></span></td>` , `<td width="33%"><span class="totalcubics"></span></td>` has to get values which are multiplied by `data-cubics="500"` from this line `val = (val ? val * $(this).data('cubics') : '');` Kindly help me on this also

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @tracktor53, i managed to get a fix for my problem, below is my updated code;

```
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" value="0"/></td>';
  html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
 $('#item_table').append(html);
  $summands = $form.find('input.qty'); //***************  added this line
 });
```

And with @mohamed's help, this line `$(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);` was looking for the next `<td>` which in actual sense, the next `<td>` was an input field but not the one with `<span id='cubics'></span>` so, i had to adjust that to this;

```
 html += '<td><input class="qty" type="text" value="0"/></td>';
  html += '<td width="33%"><span class="cubics"></span>';
```

Then after i had to use

```
$(document).on('keyup' , 'input.qty' , function () {
```

instead of

```
$('input.qty').keyup(function () {
```

Now everything is working fine only that i want to multiply `select option` values with `qty input` from this line;

```
html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'
```

Any further assistance about this is highly welcome

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();` this code will return the select value .. use parseFloat/Number to get it as integer

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef kindly update for the code as the way it should be in regards to parseFloat/Number